# Spark SQL sliding window difference computation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

How can I compute a sliding window in Spark without resorting to spark streaming?

NOTICE: I do not want to use a `WINDOW PARTITION BY ORDER BY k ROWS` before/after current one, but use the timestamp. The `window` operator has such a mode:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"a": "x", "b": "2021-02-21 01:00:00", "c": "3"},
                            {"a": "x", "b": "2021-02-21 02:00:00", "c": "4"},
                            {"a": "x", "b": "2021-02-21 03:00:00", "c": "2"}])

hour_interval = str(4) + ' hour'
sliding_window = str(60) + ' minute'
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, min, max, sum, when, lit, window, date_format
import time

df_aggregated_time_window = df.groupBy("a", window("b", windowDuration=hour_interval,
                                slideDuration=sliding_window, startTime="30 minute")).agg(min("c").alias("min_c"))
df_aggregated_time_window.show(truncate=False)

+---+------------------------------------------+-----+
|a  |window                                    |min_c|
+---+------------------------------------------+-----+
|x  |[2021-02-20 23:00:00, 2021-02-21 03:00:00]|3    |
|x  |[2021-02-21 00:00:00, 2021-02-21 04:00:00]|2    |
|x  |[2021-02-20 22:00:00, 2021-02-21 02:00:00]|3    |
|x  |[2021-02-21 02:00:00, 2021-02-21 06:00:00]|2    |
|x  |[2021-02-21 01:00:00, 2021-02-21 05:00:00]|2    |
|x  |[2021-02-21 03:00:00, 2021-02-21 07:00:00]|2    |
+---+------------------------------------------+-----+
```

My desired result would return for each of the 3 input rows 3 output rows as the sliding delta of the 4 hourly time-based window (= state) which is advanced by one hour every hour and triggered once every hour (however as this is batch, not streaming triggering should not matter so much).

Instead, I get the result above with cardinality > the number of desired rows.

### edit

Desired output:

input:

```
x,2021-02-21 01:00:00",3
x,2021-02-21 02:00:00",4
x,2021-02-21 03:00:00",4
x,2021-02-21 04:00:00",1
```

output:

```
x,2021-02-21 01:00:00", NULL // no single previous record to be found in the previous 3 hours (including self)
x,2021-02-21 02:00:00",3 // as we are currently only computing `min` for simplicity (later it should be max - min to see the deltas) within the last 3 hours the value is 3 (coincidentally the previous row)
x,2021-02-21 03:00:00",3 // within 4 hour window 3 is still the smallest
x,2021-02-21 04:00:00",1 // within the previous <= 3 hours (including self) 1 is smallest
```

Comment: did you mean to do `df.groupBy(window('b', '1 hour'))`?

Comment: No: `groupby a, window(4 hours, 1 hour)` i.e. for each a, I want compute the min/max (= delta) within the 4 hourly window of state but slide it over every 1 hour.

Comment: could you show a desired output please?

Comment: sure - please see the updated example

Comment: There seems to be something very wrong with your output, in terms of the way the `window` suppose to behave. Specifically, your definition should generate buckets starting at 30 minutes past the hour (`startTime="30 minute"`) while yours start at hour mark even.

Comment: Apart from that, 6 rows is correct since the earliest timestamp (2021-02-21 01:00:00) will fall into the interval starting at 22:00 on the previous date.

Comment: Why is 6 correct? I want to get one output row for each input computed as the state of the current hour and the previous 3 hours. And at least naively this would mean that the number of rows should not increase. Is this an incorrect assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your assumption about `window` expression is incorrect. According to its documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#window(timeColumn:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,windowDuration:String,slideDuration:String,startTime:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

> ```
> def window(timeColumn: Column, windowDuration: String, slideDuration: String, startTime: String): Column
> ```
>
> Bucketize rows into one or more time windows given a timestamp specifying column.
> Window starts are inclusive but the window ends are exclusive, e.g.
> 12:05 will be in the window [12:05,12:10) but not in [12:00,12:05).
> ...

So in your case of a 4-hour window and 1-hour sliding steps, there is going to be 6 buckets over which aggregations can be applied:

```
[2021-02-20 22:00:00, 2021-02-21 02:00:00)  <-- first bucket that contains the earliest b = 2021-02-21 01:00:00
[2021-02-20 23:00:00, 2021-02-21 03:00:00)
[2021-02-21 00:00:00, 2021-02-21 04:00:00)
[2021-02-21 01:00:00, 2021-02-21 05:00:00)
[2021-02-21 02:00:00, 2021-02-21 06:00:00)
[2021-02-21 03:00:00, 2021-02-21 07:00:00) <-- last bucket that contains the latest b = 2021-02-21 03:00:00
```

I do not entirely understand *"I do not want to use a WINDOW PARTITION BY ORDER BY..."* because that is what will allow you to efficiently fulfil your requirement *to get one output row for each input computed as the state of the current hour and the previous 3 hours*.

Comment: Using `WINDOW PARTITION BY ORDER BY.` would not be a time-based window. It would only give access to the last k records (in a SQL window) not respecting time where sometimes more or fewer records would fall into this time window.

Comment: Interesting! I was expecting to trigger the window only once for each input record and not produce intermediate (= sliding over) records in a true streaming fashion. Thanks for the clarifiaction.

Comment: Unfortunately thats true - with `WINDOW PARTITION BY ORDER BY...` we can't define a frame in time-based terms directly.