# Include groups that are excluded after grouping in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, left-join

For the sake of this question, suppose I'm counting all the values per day and hour in some silly dataframe `df`.

Imagine there are no observations on `2023-07-19`. In this case, a simple `df.groupBy('date', 'hour').count()` will return a PySpark dataframe that is missing all day-hour combinations for the day that's missing.

Is there a built-in function/method to complete the result of the `groupBy` with all possible group combinations? I can vaguely recall a `complete` or `expand` function in `dyplyr` (an R library) and I was hoping PySpark had something similar so as to avoid manually building a full catalog of combinations.

In this example, the result would look as follows:

| date | hour | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-07-18 | 22 | 3 |
| 2023-07-18 | 23 | 2 |
| 2023-07-20 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-07-20 | 2 | 3 |
| 2023-07-20 | 3 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

As you can see, the combinations (2023-07-19, 1), (2023-07-19, 2), ... (2023-07-19, 22), (2023-07-19, 23) are missing.

The result I'm looking for is:

| date | hour | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-07-18 | 22 | 3 |
| 2023-07-18 | 23 | 2 |
| 2023-07-19 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-07-19 | 2 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-07-19 | 22 | 0 |
| 2023-07-19 | 23 | 0 |
| 2023-07-20 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-07-20 | 2 | 3 |
| 2023-07-20 | 3 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

My real problem involves grouping by a few more columns, so manually building a full catalog will be tedious.

Comment: You may be talking about [`window()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66316564/spark-sql-sliding-window-difference-computation/66334195#66334195) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sequence` to create date/hour range and join to the count `df`.

```
df_seq = (df.select(F.to_timestamp(F.min('date')).alias('start'), 
                    F.to_timestamp(F.max('date')).alias('stop'))
          .select(F.sequence(F.col('start'), F.col('stop'), F.expr('interval 1 hour')).alias('seq'))
          .select(F.explode('seq').alias('seq'))
          .select(F.to_date('seq').alias('date'), 
                  F.hour('seq').alias('hour')))

# df_seq.show()
# +----------+----+
# |      date|hour|
# +----------+----+
# |2023-07-18|   0|
# |2023-07-18|   1|
# |2023-07-18|   2|
# |...
# |2023-07-20|  22|
# |2023-07-20|  23|
# +----------+----+
```

Then join with the original df.

```
df = (df_seq.join(df, on=['date', 'hour'], how='left')
      .fillna({'count': 0}))
```

Comment: This is close to what I had in mind, thank you. I was hoping there would be a built in way to complete the group combinations, but this does the trick.